# Destroying opponent's creatures with hexproof

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent has an abundance of other creatures including [Archetype of Endurance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArchetype%20of%20Endurance%5d) out, can I play cards like [Wakening Sun's Avatar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWakening%5d%2b%5bSun%27s%5d%2b%5bAvatar%5d), [Cosmotronic Wave](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCosmotronic%20Wave%5d), or the new [Rakdos, the Showstopper](http://mythicspoiler.com/rna/cards/rakdostheshowstopper.html) to get around my opponents creatures? Since they each target all of certain types of creatures and not the individual creature itself?

Or would Hexproof prevent this since the cards don't target ALL creatures?

Comment: Short answer: All of those work (although Rakdos and Sun's Avatar might kill your creatures too).  For the long answer, see the question I linked to.

Comment: Specifically, the first question applies to you. Hexproof only applies to targeting - it doesn't stop everything that might affect your opponents' creatures, including fun things like Elish Norn.

Comment: Note that none of those cards you mentioned have the word target in their abilities, so those abilities are not targeting, but field wide. Hexproof stops only one thing, targeting a creature, effects that don't say target, ignore hexproof and shroud.

Answer (score 1):

All of these cards would work since they do not specifically target any card. A creature with hexproof cannot be the target of an effect an opponent uses, however, it can still be affected by opponent's effects, so long as it is not targeted. A boardwipe will still wipe the  board, including the hexproof creatures, so long as it does not read the specific word "target." Since Wakening Sun's Avatar states "destroy all non-Dinosaur creatures," it will destroy all non-Dinosaur creatures, unless they have indestructible (permanent cannot be destroyed by rules or effects).